# Problems with If and Switch Statements in a DiceRoll project I am making

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement, dice

One of the classes I am currently working on is a DiceRoll project. One of the requirements of the project is to use nested if else statements and at least one `switch` statement. Another requirement is to give the slang for the dice roll as per this image
[Dice Roll Slang](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7g3es.png)

Here is my current code, with an explanation at the bottom:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Dice {
 public int die1;
 public int die2;
 public int total;
 public String name;
 public boolean doubles = false;

 Random random = new Random();

  public void setDie1() {
   die1 = random.nextInt(6) + 1;
  }

  public void setDie2() {
    die2 = random.nextInt(6) + 1;
  }

  public void setTotal() {
    total = die1 + die2;
  }

  public int getDie1() {
    return "Roll #1: " + die1;
  }

  public int getDie2() {
    return "Roll #2: " + die2;
  }

  public int getTotal() {
    return die1 + "plus" + die2 + "=" + total;
  }

  public boolean checkDouble() {
    if (die1 == die2) {
      doubles = true;
      return " ";
    } else {
      doubles = false;
      return " ";
    }
    return " ";
  }

  public String getName() {
    if (doubles = true){
      name = "1";
    } else if (total = 7) {
      name = "7";
    } else if (total = 5) {
      name = "5";
    } else if (total = 9) {
      name = "9";
    } else if (total = 11) {
      name = "11";
    } else if ((die1 = 1 && die2 = 2) || (die1 = 2 && die2 = 1)) {
      name = "2";
    } else if ((die1 = 4 && die2 = 2) || (die1 = 2 && die2 = 4)) {
      name = "6";
    }
  }
}
```

So my original idea was to create nested if else statements in getName. These would correspond to numbers and then I would use these numbers to make a switch statement - also in getName - that would return the dice slang depending on what number was rolled. The only problem I found with this is that since there are multiple ways to roll each number.

If the number is a six for example, you can roll a double 3, or a 2 and a 4. That means I will have to create a lot of different cases and create a very long switch statement. I also end up getting an error with the `name = "2";` and `name = "6";` statements where it is expecting a `<=` in place of the `=` for the conditions after the `&&` .

I think that there is definitely a better way to do this, but I just cannot figure it out. I am going to keep trying and working at it, but I greatly appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are making some basic mistakes.

- You can't return a `String` with a return type of `int`

```
    public int getDie1() {
       return "Roll #1: " + die1;
    }
```

Just return an int and give it a name when you print it.

- `=` is for assignment and `==` is for numerical comparison. You're comparing die values incorrectly. You do this often in your `getName()` method.

```
else if ((die1 = 1 && die2 = 2) || (die1 = 2 && die2 = 1)) {
      name = "2";
```

- You aren't returning a value in your `getName()` method.
- You can't return a `String` if the return type is a `boolean`.

```
  public boolean checkDouble() {
    if (die1 == die2) {
      doubles = true;
      return " ";
    } else {
      doubles = false;
      return " ";
    }
    return " ";
  }
```

Why not just do the following?

```
public boolean checkDouble() {
    return die1 == die2;
}
```

- A suggestion. Instead of using a setter to generate die throws, I would recommend have a `throw` method and generate them there.  Then use the getters to retrieve the values.

I get a sense that you do not understand some of the syntax basics. You must have had numerous compile time errors in your code.  You need to work on ensuring that your program compiles correctly and runs.  Then work on the execution/logic problems.

I also suggest you discuss this with your instructor.